# Remove files with Pig script after merging them

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs

I'm trying to merge a large number of small files (200k+) and have come up with the following super-easy Pig code:

```
Files = LOAD 'hdfs/input/path' using PigStorage();
store Files into 'hdfs/output/path' using PigStorage();
```

Once Pig is done with the merging is there a way to remove the input files? I'd like to check that the file has been written and is not empty (i.e. 0 bytes). I can't simply remove everything in the input path because new files may have been inserted in the meantime, so that ideally I'd remove only the ones in the `Files` variable.

Answer (score 0):

With Pig it is not possible i guess. Instead what you can do is use -tagsource with the LOAD statement and get the filename and stored it somewhere. Then use HDFS FileSystem API and read from the stored file to remove those files which are merged by pig.

```
A = LOAD '/path/' using PigStorage('delimiter','-tagsource');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use hadoop commands in your Pig script

- Move input files to a new folder
- Merge input files to output folder
- Remove input files from the new folder

> ```
> distcp 'hdfs/input/path' 'hdfs/input/new_path'
>
> Files = LOAD 'hdfs/input/new_path' using PigStorage();
> STORE Files into 'hdfs/output/path' using PigStorage();
>
> rmdir 'hdfs/input/new_path'
> ```